# Including map() function to tabulate each element in a character vector returns an error

Tags: r, string, vector, count, purrr

I'd like to tabulate the frequencies of each unitary element in a character vector. This is vector contains the answers to a set of items in a survey, with this structure "ADCDAB...", being "A" the answer to the first item, "D" to the second one, etc.
I'd like to process the data with `purrr::map` combined with base string functions.

```
p1 <- strsplit(substr(test$answer),"")
map(p1,table)
```

However, if I include the code with dplyr, the systems returns an error message:

```
 test %>% 
 mutate(p1=strsplit(answer,"")) %>% 
 map(p1,table)
```

the system returns the following error message:

```
Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 10
```

What's wrong with the second syntax?

A dummy dataset

```
structure(list(answer = c(".BBCBD.A.D", "...DB..AA.", "B......AB.", 
"BDDDBACADD", "BB.ABC.AAD"), d.n.i = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sure! The structure of the dataset is like this example:
id answers
1 .BBCBD.A.DDD.BCAAD...CC.ADD.BC
2 ...DB..AA..D.BDACD.A.C..CDDBBC
3 B......AB.BD..........C..DDBB
4 BDDDBACADDDDBDDCC.ADACCACDCB.C
5 BB.ABC.AADDDBBCDDD...CB..DDB.C

I want to tabulate, for each position, the answers. For example, for the first position, the table is:
.  2
A  0
B  3
C  0
D  0

For the second item, the table is:
.  2
A  0
B  2
C  0
D  2

And so on, until reaching the 30rd item

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to edit the previous comment,  using markdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option

```
x <- "ADCDAB"

out <- table(utf8ToInt(x))
names(out) <- intToUtf8(names(out), multiple = TRUE)
out
#A B C D 
#2 1 1 2
```

---

With multiple elements use `lapply`

```
x <- c("ADCDAB", "EFG")

f <- function(i) {
      out <- table(utf8ToInt(i))
      names(out) <- intToUtf8(names(out), multiple = TRUE)
      out
  }

lapply(x, f)
```

Returns

```
#[[1]]
#A B C D 
#2 1 1 2 

#[[2]]
#E F G 
#1 1 1
```

---

If you need output as single table, try

```
x <- c("ADCDAB", "EFGAA")
f(paste(x, collapse = ""))
#A B C D E F G 
#4 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

.. or as dataframe

```
as.data.frame(f(paste(x, collapse = "")))
#  Var1 Freq
#1    A    4
#2    B    1
#3    C    1
#4    D    2
#5    E    1
#6    F    1
#7    G    1
```

Comment: Thanks!!! However, your solution can't be applied when the character vector is a variable in a data frame. How to proceed then?

Comment: @Juan_RamonLacalle Please share dummy data in your question so we can test. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: |id | answers|
| --- | ---|
|1 | .BBCBD.A.DDD.BCAAD...CC.ADD.BC |
| 2 | ...DB..AA..D.BDACD.A.C..CDDBBC |
| 3 | B......AB.BD..........C..DDBB |
| 4 | BDDDBACADDDDBDDCC.ADACCACDCB.C |
| 5 | BB.ABC.AADDDBBCDDD...CB..DDB.C |

Comment: I'v just added a dummy dataset at the end of my post

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% mutate(p1 = strsplit(answer,""), p2 = map(p1, table))
```

---

However, I would suggest something like below :

```
test %>% 
   mutate(p1 = strsplit(answer,"")) %>%
   unnest(p1) %>%
   count(answer, p1)

#  answer p1        n
#  <chr>  <chr> <int>
#1 ABCD   A         1
#2 ABCD   B         1
#3 ABCD   C         1
#4 ABCD   D         1
#5 ADCDAB A         2
#6 ADCDAB B         1
#7 ADCDAB C         1
#8 ADCDAB D         2
```

**data**

```
test <- data.frame(answer = c("ADCDAB", "ABCD"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Your first solution seems nice. However, I don't know how to report the frequency tables of each element.
Any sugeestion!

Comment: Actually it is already there, you just don't "see" it. Try `test %>% mutate(p1 = strsplit(answer,""), p2 = map(p1, table)) %>% pull(p2)`

Comment: I've got it. Thanks!